# How to iterate through a 2d list while also accessing the elements

Tags: python, list

I have the code below which I am trying to compress with lists:

```
tmpValue += incSplit[x][y] 
tmpValue2 += incSplit2[x][y]
tmpValue3 += incSplit3[x][y]
tmpValue4 += incSplit4[x][y]
tmpValue5 += incSplit4[x][y]
```

The incSplits have been filled with matrices like this:

```
incSplit = numpy.zeros((4, 4)) 
incSplit2 = numpy.zeros((4, 4))
incSplit3 = numpy.zeros((4, 4))
incSplit4 = numpy.zeros((4, 4))
incSplit5 = numpy.zeros((4, 4))
```

Now I have listyfied the incSplits like this:

```
incSplitList = [numpy.zeros((4, 4))] * 5
```

And the tmpValues like this:

```
tmpValueList = [0] * 5
```

But I am confused in how to iterate through incSplitList while also accessing the elements x and y in the matrice like the code above: So yeah long story short: How is the below code to be compressed using the lists incSplitList and tmpValueList ?

```
tmpValue += incSplit[x][y] 
tmpValue2 += incSplit2[x][y]
tmpValue3 += incSplit3[x][y]
tmpValue4 += incSplit4[x][y]
tmpValue5 += incSplit4[x][y]
```

I am very new to programming so it would help a lot if the answers had the same variable names for me to understand better

Comment: Don't do `incSplitList = [numpy.zeros((4, 4))] * 5`, that creates a list with 5 references to the same array object

Comment: What could I do instead?

Comment: `[numpy.zeros((4,4)) for _ in range(5)]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for i in range(5):
    tmpValueList[i] += incSplitList[i][x][y]
```

This iterates the lists.

Answer (score 0):

Using enumerate which will work if your list sizes change.

```py
for i, incSplit in enumerate(incSplitList):
    tmpValueList[i] += incSplit[x][y]
```

For more info see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).